# Normality of a family of one to one analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that the set of one-to-one analytic functions on D with the property that f(0) = 0 and f′(0) = 1 is normal in the Euclidean metric. Hint: Show the family is normal on D{0}. Is the conclusion true if we eliminate the requirement f′(0) = 1? What happens if we use the chordal metric instead?

Comment: Did you have any chance to look at the answer (and that to your previous question)? I don't want to push you, but *some* feedback would be nice.

Comment: We haven't talked about Koebe distortion theorem and Montel's theorem in class yet.(I don't know why it's in my homework) I think I need to wait until the professor talks about that in class. Sorry about that.

Comment: What criteria for normality do you know?

Answer (score 1):

The family $S$ of functions which are holomorphic and univalent in 
the unit circle $\mathbb D$ and normalized with
with $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 1$  is locally uniformly bounded
according to the ["Koebe distortion theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koebe_quarter_theorem#Koebe_distortion_theorem):
$$
 |f(z)| \le \frac {|z|}{(1-|z|)^2}
$$
for all $f \in S$ and all $z \in \mathbb D$.
It follows from [Montel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem) that $S$ is
a normal family.

The condition $f'(0)=1$ cannot be dropped as the example
$f_n(z) = n z$ shows (for both euclidean and chordal metric):
$f_n(0) = 0$, but $f_n(z) \to \infty$ for $z \ne 0$, therefore
$(f_n)$ has no subsequence which converges in a neighbourhood of
$z=0$.